# Portal User's access to User Object

Tags: customer-portal, profile

I have query a query on User object

```
List<User> us = [Select AvatarId__c, CommunityNickname from User where Id = :id];
```

I am 100% sure it should return a record and it did when I run as my 'System administrator' profile. But if I run this line as portal profile, then it can't find the matched User who has another non-portal profile at all. So I get us.size() is 0.

Does anyone here can point what's the problem? For me, it looks like the portal profile doesn't have permission on users with other profile, but how can I solve this?

Thank you very much for the kind help.

Regards

Wen

Comment: Did you try changing your query to remove the where clause and verify no records are returned? That eliminates the possibility ID is somehow null in the portal user scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered to your own question. You can not have access to User object, except for the current user maybe, try with Userinfo from apex of {!$User.Email} from VF page. If not I advice you to check the related Contact of the User Portal, and maybe sync by trigger/worfklow some fields if you really need to. For non portal user, try maybe with a custom object and sync the field available for portal user. You will always have full access on a custom object.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at my question. I have to use the fields from User object on customer portal. But I don't understand what do you mean 'sync'? How to sync from User object to custom object?

Comment: create a CustomObject called PublicUser__c linked to a nonportal User, and by trigger you can populate anything you want to this object. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. It is just the trigger is quite expensive solution. Thank you for pointing the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue and tried many ways to overcome the issue, but finally got the solution by adding try catch statements. Please find the below example.

Issue Description:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY on
>   User object Debug Log:04:31:04.056
>   (56044017)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[708]|System.DmlException: Update failed.
>   First exception on row 0 with id 005F0000002F981IAC; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

Apex Method:

```
public static void disableUser(Set<ID> userIds){     
    //added try block
    try{
        List<User> lstusers = [Select id from User where id in: userIds];
        for(User u : lstusers){
            u.isActive = false;
        }
        update lstusers;//throwing error
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
}
```